# MVC4 redirect to ChildActionOly method from c# method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize-attribute

i have a custom `authorize` attribute class where i need to redirect to a Action which is decorated with `ChildActionOnly` attribute when user not authorized,

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    HttpContextBase context = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var user = AppData.CurrentUser;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.GroupName))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error/Unauthenticated");
        }
    }
}
```

and the error controller is

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ChildActionOnly]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Unauthorized() { return View(); }
    public ActionResult Unauthenticated() { return View(); }
}
```

i'm getting application error

```
The action 'Unauthorized' is accessible only by a child request.
```

Comment: you cannot redirect to a child action, child actions can only be called inline from other views using Action or RenderAction, if you want you can return a ViewResult pointing to the error views

Comment: i just need to make error controller action can only be called from inside of the application not from browser. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: A redirect *is* from the browser, not inside the application.

Comment: why your actions are only returning views, this is how mvc works, you can like i say in prev comment, return ViewResult which will render the error view back to the browser

Answer (score 0):

Why is it so dangerous that a user potentially could navigate to the `Unauthorized` action if you remove the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute? In worst case they don't get the information what page they are not supposed to see since they are not redirected from that controller/action that redirects them to this Unauthorized view. In normal case when a user is not authorized they are sent to a login page with the referrer as a url-parameter so they can be sent back once they authorize themselves, maybe not an option here?

With that said, you could with code send `TempData` when an error occours. `TempData` is a key/value-pair object that persists within an redirect so send some special value that you check for (See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx)).